# Submit for with post data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im having trouble getting the form submit to work. After  pressing submit, it indicate that the controller is not found. even when i've already define in my controller class. What i want is to get the post data in my getLoginauth function in controller.

View page

```
<div class="panel-body">
                 <?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'PortalController@getLoginauth')); ?>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value = "Login"/>
                        </fieldset>
                    <?php echo Form::close();?>
                </div>
```

Controller page

```
    class PortalController extends BaseController
{

    public function getIndex()
    {   
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            return View::make('admin_index');

        }else{
            return Redirect::to('admin/login');
        }
    }

    public function getLogin(){
        return View::make('admin_login');
    }

    public function getLoginauth(){ 
        echo 'here';
    }
}
```

Routes page

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hello');
});

Route::controller('account' , 'AccountController');
Route::controller('admin' , 'PortalController');
Route::post('admin/loginauth', 'PortalController@getLoginauth');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my form working by changing my controller function name from

```
public function getLoginauth(){ 
    echo 'here';
}
```

to

```
 public function postLoginauth(){ 
    echo 'here';
}
```

And in view page from

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'PortalController@getLoginauth')); ?>
```

to

```
 <?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/loginauth')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you form is not well-formed:

You have a route like this:

```
Route::post('admin/loginauth', 'PortalController@getLoginauth');
```

And your webform looks like this in your view:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'PortalController@getLoginauth')); ?>
```

Change it to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/loginauth')) }}
```

And for your submit button use the following blade command, which is a lot more cleaner in my opinion.

```
{{ Form::submit() }}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. However im still getting "Controller method not found" after changing my form action to url. Is there other stuff i need to set on other php file?